# How to make discord bot play audio without using ctx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

```
  async def playnext(self, message):
   if self.songQ != []:
      self.nuses = self.nuses + 1
      message.voice_client.play(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(pafy.new(self.songQ[0]).getbestaudio().url)), after=lambda error: self.removeplay(message))
   else:
      await message.channel.send("Queue is empty")
```

Im trying to create `.playnext()` method using messages, but I dont know how to form the syntax for 4th line since `message.voice_client` has no method `.play()` according to errors im getting.

I have seen people do it using `discord.ctx` like this:
`ctx.voice_client.play(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(pafy.new(self.songQ[0]).getbestaudio().url)), after=lambda error: self.removeplay(message))`

But my whole bot is built on `on_message()` function and I would like to not use discord commands in this project.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message? Because the official documentation of [Discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.play) says that VoiceClient has a play method.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, `ctx.voice_client` is a shortcut to `guild.voice_client`, so you can use that instead.

You need to define your guild first:

```py
guild = bot.get_guild(1234567890)
guild.voice_client.play(...)
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=voice%20client#discord.ext.commands.Context.voice_client

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=voice%20client#discord.Guild.voice_client

Comment: In the OPs example you can get it by `guild = message.guild`